# Entity Framework Where did my Database go?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am working on a sample program using EF. I ran the program without first making sure my SQL Database service was running, and it ran fine. But when I discovered my error, I thought that meant no Database was created and so I could simply re-run the project again and have it create the database in the running instance of SQL Express. But instead I get the invalidOperationError telling me

```
**The model backing the 'BreakAwayContext' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=238269).**
```

I am able to get around this error by applying

```
Database.SetInitializer(
new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<BreakAwayContext>());
```

but I still can't find my database.

In the config file, for defaultConnectionFactory, the setting is

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
```

So, I expect the database to be created on the installed instance of SQL 2012 on the machine, but I cannot find the database.

How do I re-set my project so it creates a new database please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like the database was created somewhere. Are you sure you're checking the correct database engine?

Comment: The SQL Express is the install on my machine, and when I check services, it is one of the only two databases on the machine. However, the Database remains missing from both.

Comment: Can you please post the connection string you're using?

Comment: I am not using any connection String in this case.

Comment: Oh I see, so you're using SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB? Have you tried using the SqlLocalDB.exe utility? There are commands to view and delete databases. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh247716.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Your database is created as a User Instance? In such case You won't see it in default instance of SQLEXPRESS using Management Studio. You can check it in Your connection string. There's a user-instance parameter. If it's set to true, then You should ba able to find and .mdf file somwhere in Your app directory.

Comment: There is no database(.mdf file) in my application directory and I did not set the connection string information so I expected CF to create the database in SQL Express.

Comment: So You got no connection string inside Your web.config or app.config?

Comment: No connection String, just expecting EF to create the database on my local which is SQLExpress